# Javascript Duplicate checkboxes check

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fictional retail website with checkboxes under each product. To make things easier I just want the code to check if the check boxes are checked and then to alert the user that they want to buy these items. I have it done with just one first but dont know where I'm going wrong.

```
var message = "";
function myFunction()
{

if (document.1.checked == true)
window.alert("Hey")

}


<label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="1" />
      </label> Add to Basket
```

Comment: Try `if (document.getElementById('1').checked)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Vanilla JavaScript way:

```
function areThereAnyCheckedCheckboxes() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var ipt = inputs[i]
        if(ipt.type.toLowerCase() === 'checkbox' && ipt.checked === true){
            alert('One of the inputs is checked!');
            break;
        }  
    }

}
```

If you use jQuery you can do this:

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
if(checkboxes.size() > 0)
   alert('One of the checkboxes is checked');
```

That will give you all checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if (document.1.checked == true)
```

in:

```
if (document.querySelector('#1').checked == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a specific checkbox was checked:

```
if(document.getElementById('1').checked) {
  alert("You checked item 1");
}
```